# Dropdown Value change if I selected the 1st Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Currently, I'm having this problem when I tried changing the value of the 1st drop down to the 2nd one also inherit the value I've selected.  Please help me with how can I fix this.

My goal is when I change the value of the first one the 2nd dropdown will not inherit the value of the first dropdown.

Please see the code below:

```js
$(".nf-default-opt").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("nf-active");
})

$(".nf-opt-ul .nf-li").click(function() {
  var currentSelected = $(this).html();
  $(".nf-default-opt .nf-li").html(currentSelected);
  $(this).parents(".nf-select-c").removeClass("nf-active");
})
```

```css
.nf-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.nf-select-c {
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.nf-select-c .nf-default-opt {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: rgb(207 213 218 / 30%) 0px 0px 0px 1px, rgb(207 213 218 / 60%) 0px 0px 2px 1px;
  min-height: 44px;
  line-height: 42px;
  height: 44px;
}

.nf-select-c .nf-default-opt .nf-li {
  padding: 0px 5px;
}

.nf-select-c .nf-default-opt::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 18px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #555555 #555555;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt-ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 46px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: none;
  box-shadow: rgb(60 64 67 / 30%) 0px 1px 2px 0px, rgb(60 64 67 / 15%) 0px 1px 3px 1px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt-ul .nf-li {
  padding: 0px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt-ul .nf-li:first-child:hover {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt-ul .nf-li:last-child:hover {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt-ul .nf-li:hover {
  background: #edf6ff;
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 44px;
  line-height: 42px;
  height: 44px;
}

.nf-icon {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-radio-btn-icon-18x18.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-s-ans {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-short-ans-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-para {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-forms-para-ans-icon18x18.png);
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-mchoice {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-radio-btn-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-checkbox {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-check-btn-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-dropdown {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-dropdown-btn-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-fupload {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-upload-icon-18x18-filled.png);
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-date {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-calendar-btn-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-time {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-time-btn-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-select-c.nf-active .nf-opt-ul {
  display: block;
}

.nf-select-c.nf-active .nf-default-opt:before {
  top: 21px;
  transform: rotate(-225deg);
}

.nf-dropdown[nf-style="2"] .nf-select-c .nf-default-opt {
  box-shadow: rgb(60 64 67 / 15%) 0px 1px 2px 0px, rgb(60 64 67 / 10%) 0px 1px 3px 1px;
  border: 0px;
}

.nf-dropdown[nf-style="2"] .nf-select-c .nf-default-opt::before {
  border-color: transparent transparent #2a79c6 #2a79c6;
}

.nf-dropdown[nf-style="2"] .nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-s-ans {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-short-ans-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-dropdown[nf-style="2"] .nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-para {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-forms-para-ans-icon18x18.png);
}

.nf-dropdown[nf-style="2"] .nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-mchoice {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-radio-btn-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-dropdown[nf-style="2"] .nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-checkbox {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-check-btn-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-dropdown[nf-style="2"] .nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-dropdown {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-dropdown-btn-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-dropdown[nf-style="2"] .nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-fupload {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-upload-icon-18x18-filled.png);
}

.nf-dropdown[nf-style="2"] .nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-date {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-calendar-btn-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-dropdown[nf-style="2"] .nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-time {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-calendar-btn-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-dropdown[nf-style="2"] .nf-icon {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-radio-btn-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-dropdown[nf-style="2"] .nf-select-c .nf-opt-ul .nf-li:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #555555;
  box-shadow: rgb(42 121 198 / 15%) 0px 2px 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nf-dropdown">
  <div class="nf-select-c">

    <div class="nf-default-opt">
      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-para" data-value="nf-para">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-para"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Paragraph</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nf-opt-ul">

      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-short-ans" data-value="nf-short-ans">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-s-ans"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Short Answer</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-para" data-value="nf-para">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-para"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Paragraph</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <hr>
      
      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-multi-choice" data-value="nf-multi">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-mchoice"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Multiple Choice</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-checkbox" data-value="nf-check">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-checkbox"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">CheckBoxes</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-dropdown" data-value="nf-dropdown">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-dropdown"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Dropdown</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <hr>
      
      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-file-upload" data-value="nf-upload">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-fupload"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">File Upload</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <hr>
      
      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-date" data-value="nf-date">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-date"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Date</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-time" data-value="nf-time">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-time"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Time</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>

              </div>

  <div class="nf-select-c">

    <div class="nf-default-opt">
      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-para" data-value="nf-para">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-para"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Paragraph</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nf-opt-ul">

      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-short-ans" data-value="nf-short-ans">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-s-ans"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Short Answer</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-para" data-value="nf-para">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-para"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Paragraph</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <hr>
      
      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-multi-choice" data-value="nf-multi">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-mchoice"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Multiple Choice</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-checkbox" data-value="nf-check">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-checkbox"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">CheckBoxes</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-dropdown" data-value="nf-dropdown">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-dropdown"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Dropdown</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <hr>
      
      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-file-upload" data-value="nf-upload">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-fupload"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">File Upload</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <hr>
      
      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-date" data-value="nf-date">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-date"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Date</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-time" data-value="nf-time">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-time"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Time</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: there is a closing div tag too much - before `<div class="nf-select-c">` or at the end...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that `$(".nf-default-opt .nf-li")` will find *all* the default-opts, so you need to use `this` to refer to the current `.nf-li` and get the closest parent `.nf-select-c` *then* find the `.nf-default-opt` within that single drop down:

```
$(this).closest(".nf-select-c").find(".nf-default-opt .nf-li").html(currentSelected);
```

As you also removeClass, this can be combined:

```
  var currentSelected = $(this).html();
  var wrapper = $(this).closest(".nf-select-c");
  wrapper.find(".nf-default-opt .nf-li").html(currentSelected);
  wrapper.removeClass("nf-active");
```

```js
$(".nf-default-opt").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("nf-active");
})

$(".nf-opt-ul .nf-li").click(function() {
  var currentSelected = $(this).html();
  var wrapper = $(this).closest(".nf-select-c");
  wrapper.find(".nf-default-opt .nf-li").html(currentSelected);
  wrapper.removeClass("nf-active");
})
```

```css
.nf-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.nf-select-c {
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.nf-select-c .nf-default-opt {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: rgb(207 213 218 / 30%) 0px 0px 0px 1px, rgb(207 213 218 / 60%) 0px 0px 2px 1px;
  min-height: 44px;
  line-height: 42px;
  height: 44px;
}

.nf-select-c .nf-default-opt .nf-li {
  padding: 0px 5px;
}

.nf-select-c .nf-default-opt::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 18px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #555555 #555555;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt-ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 46px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: none;
  box-shadow: rgb(60 64 67 / 30%) 0px 1px 2px 0px, rgb(60 64 67 / 15%) 0px 1px 3px 1px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt-ul .nf-li {
  padding: 0px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt-ul .nf-li:first-child:hover {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt-ul .nf-li:last-child:hover {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt-ul .nf-li:hover {
  background: #edf6ff;
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 44px;
  line-height: 42px;
  height: 44px;
}

.nf-icon {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-radio-btn-icon-18x18.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-s-ans {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-short-ans-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-para {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-forms-para-ans-icon18x18.png);
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-mchoice {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-radio-btn-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-checkbox {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-check-btn-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-dropdown {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-dropdown-btn-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-fupload {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-upload-icon-18x18-filled.png);
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-date {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-calendar-btn-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-time {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-time-btn-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-select-c.nf-active .nf-opt-ul {
  display: block;
}

.nf-select-c.nf-active .nf-default-opt:before {
  top: 21px;
  transform: rotate(-225deg);
}

.nf-dropdown[nf-style="2"] .nf-select-c .nf-default-opt {
  box-shadow: rgb(60 64 67 / 15%) 0px 1px 2px 0px, rgb(60 64 67 / 10%) 0px 1px 3px 1px;
  border: 0px;
}

.nf-dropdown[nf-style="2"] .nf-select-c .nf-default-opt::before {
  border-color: transparent transparent #2a79c6 #2a79c6;
}

.nf-dropdown[nf-style="2"] .nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-s-ans {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-short-ans-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-dropdown[nf-style="2"] .nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-para {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-forms-para-ans-icon18x18.png);
}

.nf-dropdown[nf-style="2"] .nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-mchoice {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-radio-btn-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-dropdown[nf-style="2"] .nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-checkbox {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-check-btn-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-dropdown[nf-style="2"] .nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-dropdown {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-dropdown-btn-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-dropdown[nf-style="2"] .nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-fupload {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-upload-icon-18x18-filled.png);
}

.nf-dropdown[nf-style="2"] .nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-date {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-calendar-btn-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-dropdown[nf-style="2"] .nf-select-c .nf-opt .nf-icon._nf-icon-time {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-calendar-btn-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-dropdown[nf-style="2"] .nf-icon {
  background-image: url(../media/icons/noah-form-radio-btn-icon-18x18.png);
}

.nf-dropdown[nf-style="2"] .nf-select-c .nf-opt-ul .nf-li:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #555555;
  box-shadow: rgb(42 121 198 / 15%) 0px 2px 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nf-dropdown">
  <div class="nf-select-c">

    <div class="nf-default-opt">
      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-para" data-value="nf-para">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-para"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Paragraph</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nf-opt-ul">

      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-short-ans" data-value="nf-short-ans">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-s-ans"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Short Answer</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-para" data-value="nf-para">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-para"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Paragraph</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-multi-choice" data-value="nf-multi">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-mchoice"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Multiple Choice</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-checkbox" data-value="nf-check">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-checkbox"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">CheckBoxes</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-dropdown" data-value="nf-dropdown">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-dropdown"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Dropdown</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-file-upload" data-value="nf-upload">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-fupload"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">File Upload</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-date" data-value="nf-date">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-date"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Date</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-time" data-value="nf-time">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-time"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Time</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="nf-select-c">

    <div class="nf-default-opt">
      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-para" data-value="nf-para">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-para"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Paragraph</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nf-opt-ul">

      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-short-ans" data-value="nf-short-ans">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-s-ans"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Short Answer</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-para" data-value="nf-para">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-para"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Paragraph</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-multi-choice" data-value="nf-multi">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-mchoice"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Multiple Choice</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-checkbox" data-value="nf-check">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-checkbox"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">CheckBoxes</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-dropdown" data-value="nf-dropdown">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-dropdown"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Dropdown</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-file-upload" data-value="nf-upload">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-fupload"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">File Upload</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-date" data-value="nf-date">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-date"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Date</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="nf-li">
        <div class="nf-opt _nf-time" data-value="nf-time">
          <div class="nf-icon _nf-icon-time"></div>
          <div class="nf-p">Time</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: like in the question there is a closing div tag too much - before `<div class="nf-select-c">` or at the end...

Comment: @biberman does make it clearer which is the relevant parent though - I wasn't sure at first if it was nf-select-c nf-dropdown - removing extra div makes that clearer

Comment: Thanks for the great answer @freedomn-m it really helps a lot. Already checking on it :) Thanks a lot again

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the 2nd line of your 2nd click callback.

`$(".nf-default-opt .nf-li").html(currentSelected);`

Intead of updating the content of all `.nf-default-opt .nf-li` (there are 2), you should call `.html` on only the element of your choice.